# Uninstalling simpleform gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have commented out gem 'simple_form' from my Gemfile with Rails Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 2.0.0p0. When I do `rails generate scaffold`, I still get simple_form forms.

Is there a way to get the original `form_for` scaffolds instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should remove it properly:

```
# rails destroy simple_form:install 
# bundle
```

Also, you can check for files in lib/templates and remove the associated ones for simple_form.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form?view=comments#comment_150699
http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/680

Comment: I saw that post and tried it.. I got Could not find generator simple_form:install.

Comment: Have you tried to do a gem uninstall simple_form beyond just the bundle for the Rails app?

Comment: Also, you can check for files in lib/templates and remove the associated ones for simple_form. Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/680

Comment: This is it! Something was left in lib/templates :-) Would you care to make your answer more general above so I would accept it as the solution?

Comment: Updated original post with additional solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try after installing bundle again,

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I have uninstalled the simple_form gem and did bundle install, still getting simple_form_for ; is it possible that Rails 3.2.12 is has simple_form included?